# No WebApplicationContext found?

Tags: spring, jsf-2

I'm having trouble with my spring + jsf configuration.
I have used WebApplicationInitializer to load ContextLoaderListener and RequestContextListener.

```
public class Initializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    @Override
    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        ctx.register(WebAppConfig.class);

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(ctx));
        servletContext.addListener(new RequestContextListener());
    }
}
```

WebAppConfig class:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"web.beans","web.config","web.services"})
public class WebAppConfig { 
}
```

In my faces-config.xml I have:

```
<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
```

And my web.xml is pretty standard:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>SpringWeb</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF   Specification 2.5.2</description>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

My pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>web</groupId>
<artifactId>SpringWeb</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <jsf.version>2.1.3</jsf.version>
    <spring.version>3.2.5.RELEASE</spring.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.9</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Spring implementation -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
        <version>${spring.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- CGLIB is required to process @Configuration classes -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>cglib</groupId>
        <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Jsf -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.web</groupId>
      <artifactId>el-impl</artifactId>
      <version>2.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>4.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Im running app on Tomcat 7 and here is my stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
org.springframework.web.jsf.FacesContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(FacesContextUtils.java:83)
org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver.getWebApplicationContext(SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java:91)
org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver.getBeanFactory(SpringBeanFacesELResolver.java:79)
org.springframework.beans.factory.access.el.SpringBeanELResolver.getValue(SpringBeanELResolver.java:50)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver._getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:176)
com.sun.faces.el.DemuxCompositeELResolver.getValue(DemuxCompositeELResolver.java:203)
org.apache.el.parser.AstIdentifier.getValue(AstIdentifier.java:72)
org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:161)
```

From what I gathered in spring docs, WebApplicationInitializer  and web.xml(3.0) are complementary, so I cant figure out what's wrong...

Big thx in advance

Update: 
On first deploy I get error, on second deploy the app starts

Comment: Make sure that your web.xml is actually a 3.0 version and make sure that you don't have `metadata-complete="true"` in your header. Also why are you mixing a web.xml and `WebApplicationInitializer`? Why don't you simply add the servlet to the initializer as well?

Comment: it is 3.0 version, I dont have metadata-complete="true". Thing is, I don't know how to add javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet to initalizer :-)

Comment: The same as a filter but by using the `addServlet` method. I suggest you take a look at the [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#addServlet(java.lang.String, java.lang.Class)) for `ServletContext`. Also can you post/add the header of your web.xml (for completness sake).

Comment: ok did, but I dont get it, are they not complementary?

Comment: Another thing I would expect the `servlet-api` en `el-impl` (at least the first) to have `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Comment: ok, changed scope to provided, but now app fails to start first time but loads ok on second deploy??? mb I have load order wrong?

Comment: In your web-apps `META-INF` directory add a `context.xml` file and add `<Context logEffectiveWebXml="true" />` (or if you already have this file add the attribute). This will log the generated `web.xml`. Also as mentioned make sure you don't include the Servlet-API as this will lead to classloading issues (i.e. a `ServletContainerInitializer` not being a `ServletContainerInitializer` due to different classloaders). Enable DEBUG logging for Spring and see what is happening during load-time.

Comment: ok, did it, is's just bunch of <mime-mapping> and same exception as before

Comment: Please add the generated/used web.xml and the DEBUG (preferabbly TRACE) output from Spring. Check the logs (catalina.out) for messages containing **Spring WebApplicationInitializer** it should log if something and what got detected.

Comment: Hm, you were right on money, it appears it was <scope>provided</scope> issue. After I cleaned up and updated project with maven it started on the first time. Please could you write an answer so I can accept it. Big thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your maven configuration specifies 2 dependencies as **compile** (the default) whereas they should be specified as **provided**. At least the servlet-api should be scoped as **provided**

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.0</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Problem with adding the servlet-api to your war file is that it will (might) lead to class-loading issues. The same class is available in 2 different class-loaders and as such a `ServletContainerInitializer` from CL1 isn't the same as a `ServletContainerInitializer` from CL2 (class identity is based on class-name + classloader).

This leads to not detecting the `SpringServletContainerInitializer`, which is responsible for loading the `WebApplicationInitializer` implementations.